# Block is bigger than it should be

Tags: html, css

So I was creating a design and when I tested it the border was a bit out on the left from the content. It didn't create a border right around the content inside, it created a bigger border.

HTML

```
<ul id="profile_stats">
<li class="top"><b>100</b><br /><i>short</i></li>
<li class="top"><b>100</b><br /><i>long</i></li>
<li class="top"><b>100</b><br /><i>images</i></li><br />
<li class="bottom"><b>10</b><br /><i>friends</i></li>
<li class="bottom"><b>10</b><br /><i>followers</i></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul#profile_stats {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    width: 180px;
}

ul#profile_stats li {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul#profile_stats .top {
    width: 60px;
    background: #B0B0B0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.top:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
}

.top:not(:nth-of-type(3)) {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

ul#profile_stats .bottom {
    width: 90px;
    background: #555;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rU8N9/8/

Comment: Is it valid to have a `<br />` as a childnode of an `ul`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default most browsers render ul with some left-side padding, I think that's what's interfering with your design, try:

```
ul {padding-left: 0;}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
```

Comment: what happened to `ul {padding: 0;}`?